# Duplicating records in R and inputting a new column with a different value for each duplicated record

Tags: r, duplicates, transpose

For the below I need to 
1) duplicate all the rows in file 1 equal to the number rows in file 2 
2) then I need to add a value to each duplicated record from file 2.

Please see below. Any help is appreciated

```
File 1
    Gen     Type    V1   
    AB      Wind    67   
    CB      Gas     20   
    YY      Wind    43   
    RR      Wind    44   

File 2
    Time
    17:00
    17:30
    18:00
```

Duplicate Values in File 1 and add values to file 2. The values in file 2 needs to align fully with the values in file 1.

```
New File 
    Gen     Type    V1   Time
    AB      Wind    67   17:00
    CB      Gas     20   17:00
    YY      Wind    43   17:00
    RR      Wind    44   17:00
    AB      Wind    67   17:30
    CB      Gas     20   17:30
    YY      Wind    43   17:30
    RR      Wind    44   17:30
    AB      Wind    67   18:00
    CB      Gas     20   18:00
    YY      Wind    43   18:00
    RR      Wind    44   18:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is `crossing` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
crossing(df1, df2)
# A tibble: 12 x 4
#  Gen   Type     V1 Time 
#   <chr> <chr> <int> <chr>
# 1 AB    Wind     67 17:00
# 2 AB    Wind     67 17:30
# 3 AB    Wind     67 18:00
# 4 CB    Gas      20 17:00
# 5 CB    Gas      20 17:30
# 6 CB    Gas      20 18:00
# 7 RR    Wind     44 17:00
# 8 RR    Wind     44 17:30
# 9 RR    Wind     44 18:00
#10 YY    Wind     43 17:00
#11 YY    Wind     43 17:30
#12 YY    Wind     43 18:00
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Gen = c("AB", "CB", "YY", "RR"), Type = c("Wind", 
"Gas", "Wind", "Wind"), V1 = c(67L, 20L, 43L, 44L)), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

df2 <- structure(list(Time = c("17:00", "17:30", "18:00")), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun. That answers the question.